# Hide shipping address in WooCommerce new order email notification depending on shipping method id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, shipping-method

I want to hide the shipping address if the shipping label is called "Pick up at Rockefeller Store" (but to show for other pickup methods).

There are too many ids such as "local_pickup:3" for me to filter through. I enabled the shipping address to be shown in [emails/email-addresses.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/templates/emails/email-addresses.php) despite it being a local pickup method.

My code attempt:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Email Addresses
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates\Emails
 * @version 3.9.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
$address    = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
$shipping   = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();


?><table id="addresses" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 40px; padding:0;" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border:0; padding:0;" valign="top" width="50%">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <address class="address">
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( $address ? $address : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
                <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                    <br/><?php echo wc_make_phone_clickable( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <br/><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </address>
        </td>
        <?php if ( $shipping ) : ?>
            <td style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; padding:0;" valign="top" width="50%">
                <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

                <address class="address"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $shipping ); ?></address>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

I need this to be enabled as some of our other pickup methods require it. And I am trying to have it so that if it is solely "Pick up at Rockefeller Store" then it should hide the shipping address in new order WooCommerce email.

How would I filter this based on its text label as shown in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$shipping_local_pickup = false;
        if ( $items_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
            foreach ( $items_totals as $items_total ) {
                if ( $items_total['value'] == 'Pick Up at Rockefeller Store' && !$shipping_local_pickup ) $shipping_local_pickup = true;
            }
        }
```

Adding this to my template worked then setting line 48 to `!$shipping_local_pickup`

This allows me to choose the phrase "Pick Up at Rockefeller Store" used in the table and not display the shipping address it if it is present.

Answer was taken and edited from [Hide shipping address on local pickup in WooCommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936283/hide-shipping-address-on-local-pickup-in-woocommerce-email-notifications?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to edit template files as it is possible via hooks. This answer consists of 2 parts:

**1)** The first part only needs to be **executed once and serves as debug information.** The following text will **appear in the new order mail**

> DEBUG INFORMATION, shipping method id = **THE_SHIPPING_METHOD_ID**

**Part 1:**

```php
// DEBUG information
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {           
    // Only for 'new order'
    if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
        // Get shipping methods
        foreach ( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ) {
            // Get method ID
            $shipping_method_id = $shipping_method->get_method_id();

            // Output
            echo '<p>DEBUG INFORMATION, shipping method id = ' . $shipping_method_id . '</p>';
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );
```

**NOTE:** After the correct information is known, you should **no longer use part 1**

---

**2)** Then you can use the 2nd part of my answer,
where you need to replace `REPLACE_THIS_WITH_THE_SHIPPING_METHOD_ID` with `THE_SHIPPING_METHOD_ID`, **that information comes from the first part of my answer**

**Part 2:**

```php
// Setting the email_is as a global variable
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {           
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );

function filter_woocommerce_order_hide_shipping_address( $shipping_method_id, $order ) {
    // Getting the email ID global variable
    $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_id = isset( $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'] ) ? $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'] : '';

    // Only for 'new order'
    if ( $email_id == 'new_order' ) {
        // Replace the 2nd part in the array with the 'shipping_method_id' from the DEBUG INFORMATION
        $shipping_method_id = array( 'local_pickup', 'REPLACE_THIS_WITH_THE_SHIPPING_METHOD_ID' );
    } else {
        // Default
        $shipping_method_id = array( 'local_pickup' );  
    }
    
    return $shipping_method_id;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_hide_shipping_address', 'filter_woocommerce_order_hide_shipping_address', 10, 2 );
```

---

**NOTE:** Since the email id is not known in the 2nd part of my answer, a workaround is used for this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574008/11987538

Comment: Thank you for this, however my problem is that I have two local_pickup methods. One is called "Pick Up at Rockefeller Store" and the other is "Messenger Service." Even though "Messenger Service" is not technically a local pick up, I need to it be so that it shares a calendar in the checkout page. So my question is how can I differentiate more in depth between the two local_pickup method IDs since they are both the same. Would there be a way to call $shipping_method_id = $shipping_method->get_method_value() or $shipping_method_id = $shipping_method->get_method_label();?

Comment: @Buttsilio Yes, that is certainly possible. However, I see that you have already applied a solution by modifying the template file (which is also possible, but less recommended, considering future updates of WooCommerce). 
I thought your question was only about new order email notifications, and this doesn't seem to have been taken into account in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a way to hide the address and other fields for local pickup method I see this reply https://wpsimplehacks.com/how-to-hide-woocommerce-checkout-fields-when-local-pickup-is-selected/

This is the code and works for me:

```
// Hide Local Pickup shipping method
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'hide_local_pickup_method' );
function hide_local_pickup_method( $fields_pickup ) {
    // change below for the method
    $shipping_method_pickup ='local_pickup:4';
    // change below for the list of fields. Add (or delete) the field name you want (or don’t want) to use
    $hide_fields_pickup = array( 'billing_company', 'billing_country', 'billing_postcode', 'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2' , 'billing_city', 'billing_state');
 
    $chosen_methods_pickup = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_pickup = $chosen_methods_pickup[0];
 
    foreach($hide_fields_pickup as $field_pickup ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['required'] = false;
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'hide_pickup';
        }
        $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic_pickup';
    }
    return $fields_pickup;
}
// Local Pickup - hide fields
add_action( 'wp_head', 'local_pickup_fields', 999 );
function local_pickup_fields() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <style>
        .hide_pickup {display: none!important;}
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }
            $(document).on( 'change', '#shipping_method input[type="radio"]', function() {
                // change local_pickup:4 accordingly
            $('.billing-dynamic_pickup').toggleClass('hide_pickup', this.value == 'local_pickup:4');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

If you need to hide the "send to different address" on checkout page try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'hide_ship_to_section' );
  
function hide_ship_to_section( $available_gateways ) {
    
   $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
   $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
   if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup' ) ) {
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery('#customer_details .col-2').fadeOut();
      </script>
   <?php  
   } 
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery('form.checkout').on('change','input[name^="shipping_method"]',function() {
            var val = jQuery( this ).val();
            if (val.match("^local_pickup")) {
                     jQuery('#customer_details .col-2').fadeOut();
               } else {
               jQuery('#customer_details .col-2').fadeIn();
            }
         });
      </script>
   <?php
  
}
```

All credit is for Janek T, couldn´t find his profile at stackoverflow